# WebDeploy - VS Community 2013 and Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, webdeploy, iis-8.5

I am getting Time "Couldn't connect to the remote computer" error. I was able to Telnet to the 8172 port from my local machine. I have Web Deploy installed on the server and also the **Web Management Service**, which is running fine. Supply the following parameter on the Publish Web screen to validate Connection.

```
Server:          https://111.111.1.111:8172/msdeploy.axd
Site name:       CCPTest
Username:        Uname
Passowrd:        Pword
Destination URL: http://111.111.1.111:82
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the permissions are set correctly

Check that on your server 111.111.1.111:

[image: img1]

And into the "Configure Web Deploy Publishing" do de setup:

[image]